# sscanf failing on splitting string to double values

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I do  not know what mistake I am making here. But sscanf is not filling up the values in my double arrays (first indexes). here is code

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter the number of equations" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    string coeffData;
    string powerData;
    double m_coeff_X[5] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    double m_coeff_Y[5] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    double m_coeff_Z[5] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    double m_coeff_V[5] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    double m_coeff_W[5] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    double m_const[5] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the coefficients for Number " << i+1 <<
                " equation. x,y,z,v,w (separated by commas)" << endl;
        cin >> coeffData;

        if (sscanf(coeffData.c_str(), "%f,%f,%f,%f,%f", 
            &m_coeff_X[i], &m_coeff_Y[i], &m_coeff_Z[i],
            &m_coeff_V[i], &m_coeff_W[i]) == 1) {
            cout << "value was ok";
        } else {
            cout << "value was not ok";
        }
        cout << m_coeff_X[i] << endl;
        cout << m_coeff_Y[i] << endl;
        cout << m_coeff_Z[i] << endl;
        cout << m_coeff_V[i] << endl;
        cout << m_coeff_W[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I run the loop only once for the time being. Which means i=0 and thats all ..

The output is:

```
Enter the coefficients for Number 1 equation. x,y,z,v,w (separated by commas)
1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0
value was not ok
5.26354e-315
5.30499e-315
5.32571e-315
5.34643e-315
5.3568e-315
```

**EDIT**: Thanks for reminding me that it is %lf but not %f. I did it like this but was playing with the code. After fixing this problem, I get this output:

```
Enter the coefficients for Number 1 equation. x,y,z,v,w (separated by commas)
1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0
value was not ok
1
2
3
4
5
```

I did this way first, the thing is, when I print these doubles, they print as integers, I am confused why it is so, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) should return "5" (the #/items found), not "1".  Also use "%lf" for "double" (and "%f" for float).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong format in `sscanf` for `doubles`, it should be `%lf` instead of `%f`.  Compiling with warnings enabled, such as with `g++ -Wall -W` would have caught this syntax error gracefully.  `sscanf()` parses floating point numbers, as instructed and stores them as `floats` into the memory actually used by the program as `doubles`.  This invokes undefined behaviour.

Your program could crash.  Here it seems to store meaningless values in these `double` variables.  More precisely, it only modifies half the bytes of the `double` variables. `floats` and `doubles` usually have a different representation in memory.

Furthermore, the return value of this `sscanf()` call should be compared to `5`, not `1`.`sscanf` returns the number of fields successfully converted.  This is the reason why your program outputs `value was not ok`.

Regarding the output, the numbers output like integers because they have integral values.  You can control the way you convert numbers to strings with `snprintf()`.  It would be consistent to do so since you use `sscanf()` as well.  Some more elaborate and IMHO ill conceived API exist to control conversion with iostreams and the `<<` operator.  I would advise strongly against these because they have side effects on `cout` that are not easy to revert.

Comment: can you please check the edited question now. Thanks for pointing that out ! I do not get double values when i print them again. I get integers .. why is it so ?

Answer (score 2):

For double you need to use %lf not %f

Comment: Compiling with warnings enabled, such as `gcc -Wall -W` would have caught this syntax error gracefully.

Comment: You should not edit the question this way.  It makes the answers inconsistent.

Comment: @k2ibegin: I edited your question to keep it consistent with the answers. Also note how proper indentation and line wrapping improves readability.